# Hibernate one to many mapping select query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

Suppose i have a student and phone entity with one to many relation ship with a seperate relation table

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "STUDENT")
  public class Student {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_PHONE", joinColumns = { 
  @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_ID") })
private Set<Phone> studentPhoneNumbers = new 
    HashSet<Phone>(0);
 } 

@Entity
@Table(name = "PHONE")
 public class Phone {
 }
```

I need to write an inner join query either usinv hql or projection to fetch the list of student with list if phone number for each student... How it is possible....

Query will be something like

```
Select * from student, phone, STUDENT_PHONE where name 
 like  't%'
```

Final output will be list < Student>

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what student's criteria you are looking for but the hql query to join your table can be written like this :

```
select s from Student s join s.studentPhoneNumbers spn where ....
```

Then you can add anything you want in the where like

```
... spn.name like 't%'
```